# Custom listview click listener not working perfectly

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I just needed help with a tricky situation in listview click listner. The thing is that I have populated a listview with custom adapters from remote servers. My listview contains 4 elements 2 images and 2 textview so the listview is loading perfectly from database but the issue is that I want listview to work only if the certain conditions match. Have a look at my code:

```
   if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

        }


        ImageView team1_photo,team2_photo;
        TextView tournament;


        team1_photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team1);
        team2_photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.team2);
        tournament=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tournament);
        status=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);



        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(live_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam1_photo(), team1_photo);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(live_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam2_photo(), team2_photo);
        tournament.setText(live_conveyerList.get(position).getTournament());
        status.setText(live_conveyerList.get(position).getStatus());


        liveListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                    switch (position) {
                                                        case 0:
                                                            if(status.getText().equals("play on"))
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Result will be declared shortly",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                                            }
                                                            else {
                                                                Intent fix1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Leaderboard.class);
                                                                startActivity(fix1);
                                                            }
                                                            break;
                                                        case 1:

                                                            if(status.getText().equals("play on"))
                                                        {

                                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result will be declared shortly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                                        }
                                                        else{

                                                                Intent fix2 = new Intent(getActivity(), Leaderboard_1.class);
                                                                startActivity(fix2);

                                                            }
                                                            break;

                                                        default:


                                                    }

                                                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in, R.anim.activity_out);


                                                }
                                            }


        );



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So here, status is one of the textviews and it has two type of outputs. One is "play on" and other is "play off" so I want to open new activity only when it has populated play on in that peculiar row. Els,e there should be a toast only, 
but it is not working for me. Any help would be nice, thanks.

my json is like this

```
{"list":[{"tournament":"Xavier college League","team1_photo":"http:\/\/thehostels.in\/judgement_files\/images\/India.png","team2_photo":"http:\/\/thehostels.in\/judgement_files\/images\/Australia.png","status":"play on"},{"tournament":"ITM college League","team1_photo":"http:\/\/thehostels.in\/judgement_files\/images\/India.png","team2_photo":"http:\/\/thehostels.in\/judgement_files\/images\/Australia.png","status":"play off"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case 0 you have "Play on" with a capital P, but equals takes the case into account by default, could it be your issue?

Edit :  Ok I think I got it
You define the onItemClickListener not once but for each and every item, so that at the end of list population, your listener is based on the status of the last item of your list
You should define onItemClickListener only once, and you will have clicked item with view and position arguments

For instance you may want to store the list of all your items as a field, and in your onItemClickListener you will get clicked item from the position, and thus get its status

With the view parameter, you should be able to access the fields' values through findViewById

Edit 2:
What I meant is the following : there is only one onItemClickListener that needs to be defined and onItemClick method will provide the position and the view of clicked item.
That means that each time user will click any item of the list, the listener will be called, but there is not one different listener for each different row.

With that in mind, in the onItemClick, with the view and/or the position, you can access the status textview, get its value and then do all the stuff you need to do with your toast and intent. I hope it's clearer than before

Edit 3:
That should do your thing : in your listener, before your switch,
TextView currentStatus=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

And then you replace all the references to status inside your listener by currentStatus. And you will need to define the listener only once outside of your getView method, even outside your adapter, rather where your listView is defined and your adapter is added to it

Comment: no thats only typo i have checked the string , its ok

Comment: What particularly is not working? What buggy behavior would you have?

Comment: actually, the listview is not checking the condition it is only executing whatever is written first like if the toast is before intent then it shows toast for all the conditions and if the intent is first then it opens new activity, in short, it does not care about the string of status textview at all...

Comment: i think i didn't get you but you have written that i have  define listener for  each and every item so what do you mean by that ,as I think i have set conditions for every row according to position as you would be knowing that 'status' textview is dynamically changing according to remote server so how would it be possible to do what you said , i hope i made sense

Comment: What I meant is the following : there is only one onItemClickListener that needs to be defined and onItemClick method will provide the position and the view of clicked item. That means that each time user will click any item of the list, the listener will be called, but there is not one different listener for each different row. With that in mind, in the onItemClick, with the view and/or the position, you can access the status textview, get its value and then do all the stuff you need to do with your toast and intent. I hope it's clearer than before

Comment: i got you fully so just tell me how would i able to get the 'status' textview's current text something like that i have tried so far  status.getText().equals("match in progress") but i don't know anything beyond that...

Comment: what i mean is how to add that position stuff in my status value.. and sorry if the question sounds like dumb as i am relatively new in the android

Comment: That should do your thing : in your listener, before your switch, TextView currentStatus=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status); 
And then you replace all the references to status inside your listener by currentStatus. And you will need to define the listener only once outside of your getView method, even outside your adapter, rather where your listView is defined and your adapter is added to it

Comment: bang on, it worked like a charm, a very warm thank you to you and have a great Sunday wherever you are